# Late Activating a JavaScript Control

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

On my Razor View i have a Kendo Control that will be rendered as string.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("MyPicker").ToString())
```

The output on the rendered page looks like this:

```
<input id="MyPicker" name="MyPicker" type="text" />
<script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#MyPicker").kendoDatePicker({"format":"dd.MM.yyyy","min":new Date(1900,0,1,0,0,0,0),"max":new Date(2099,11,31,0,0,0,0)});});
</script>
```

Is it possible to activate this control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it was quite simple:

```
$("#MyPicker").kendoDatePicker();
```